# Using php string parsing to get the folder name in this string

Tags: php, string, parsing

Suppose I have the following string in php:

```
"somedirectory/abc/morethings/[folder name]"
```

How can I parse it so I get '[folder name]' from that directory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function:

```
$folder_name = basename("somedirectory/abc/morethings/foldername");
```

`$folder_name` will be `"foldername"`.

Comment: Didn't even know about `basename()` +1